# Low Resolution on Log In Start Up on Win7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I have a laptop with Win7 Pro and a Logitech solar powered keyboard. The resolution was set at the highest one (1920x1080).I was cleaning my keyboard one day, the laptop was in sleep mode or locked, and when I 'woke'/unlocked it, 
 the resolution was at 1280x720. So, I changed it, hit 'apply' and then 'ok' (just to be sure) and it still comes up with the lower resolution. Its probably something simple (I'm hoping) seeing as its my work laptop.

Comment: Try WindowsKey + P to toggle display mode. If its in duplicate/extend/projector mode right now that would explain the lower resolution.